# How to get the Char a const * TCHAR pointer points to

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I've got some problems with a pointer

```
void getPartOfString(const TCHAR * wholeString)
{
    const TCHAR * pPointer = NULL;
    pPointer = _tcsstr(wholeString, searchedString); //searching for a special string in string
    pPointer += _tcslen(searchedString); //set pointer to the beginning of the string wanted
    //here I want to check if the char, the pointer points to is a space and if it is set it forward
}
```

So, how can I get rid of that space?

Answer (score 5):

If I understood the question correctly:

```
if (*pPointer == _T(' '))
    ++pPointer;
```

The `_T` macro ensures that the result is always of type `TCHAR`, whether `TCHAR` is defined as `char` (ANSI) or as `wchar_t` (Unicode).

Comment: @Stefenie: The customary way to thank somebody for a correct answer on stackoverflow is to mark that answer as accepted.